# batch to find string and copy next few characters

Tags: batch-file

Basically I have 132 text files. Each text file includes the string:

> f**X**.item.r=arabe%20coran.zoom.zoom","options":[{"name":"zoom","data":{"_width":

Where **X** represents the text file's name (which is a number from 1 to 132).

A portion of the text in file named "3" would look like the following:

> Bservices/ajax/mode/SINGLE/ark:/12148/btv1b10510341k/f3.item.r=arabe%20coran.zoom.zoom","options":[{"name":"zoom","data":{"_width":3652,"_height":2729,"_id":"ark:/12148/btv1b10510341k/f3","_context":library/iiif/image-

and the entire text is in one line.

What I am trying to achieve is to  get the number after `width":` (which is 3652 in file 3) and the number after `height":`(which is 2729 in file 3), for all files, printed out to a text file named `OutputXY.txt` in the following format:

```
1 (TAB) 4724 (TAB) 7392
2 (TAB) 8126 (TAB) 3021
3 (TAB) 3652 (TAB) 2729
```

This is what I could come up with till now

```
@echo off

SET File=1
SET Search="meow"

:LOOP
SET Search=f%File%.item.r=arabe%%20coran.zoom.zoom""","""options""":[{"""name""":"""zoom""","""data""":{"""_width""":

findstr %Search% %File%.txt) >> OutputXY.txt REM(I want this function to somehow print the width and the height to OutputXY.txt)

SET /A File=File+1
If "%File%" LEQ "132"(
GOTO LOOP
) else (
pause
exit
)
```

Also, I cannot directly search for `width":` nor `height':`, as there are other widths and heights in the file. I have to search for that specific code.

I am a complete noob in all kinds of programming. I don't know what to do now plse halp .-.

Thank you so much

Comment: So the `/fX.item.r` portion is unique in each file? is it at the beginning of a line, or could it occur anywhere? are the `_width` and `_height` keywords of interest the first ones in the files, or the first ones after the `/fX.item.r` portion? do the file names have an extension `.txt`?

Comment: No, the fX.item.r portion is not unique in each file. There are multiple `fX.item.r=arabe%20coran.zoom.zoom","options":[{"name":"zoom","data":{"_width":` in each file, and they are not in a specific place, but I want the width and the height of the one where X is the same as the text file's name. And yes, all files which I want to examine are in .txt extension.

Comment: So supposing `X` is the respective file name, `/fX.item.r` occurs once... do the keywords `_width` and `_height` of interest occur in the same line as the preceding `/fX.item.r` pattern?

Comment: I just recognized a second part `/f3` in your sample data for file `3.txt`; can this be seen as the end of the interesting portion? are there only unique occurrences of `_width` and `_height` between `/f3.item.r` and `/f3`?

Comment: How long are the lines in all the text files? regard that there is a limit of 8190 characters in command prompt, wher trying to read the file...

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
break>output.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /R "\/f[0-9].*\.item\." *.txt') do (
  set line=%%a
  set _file=!line:*/f=!
  set _width=!line:*"_width":=!
  set _height=!line:*"_height":=!
  for /f "delims=.," %%b in ('set _') do set %%b
 >>output.txt echo !_file!  !_width!    !_height!
)
type output.txt
```

I'm not quite happy with a search string of simply`/f` (for the file). I't quite short and therefore maybe not unique enough. Although it seems to work well with your given example.

Answer (score 0):

It is *very* difficult to specify such complex search strings in pure batch scripts, because there are many characters that have special meanings, like `"` `%` `,` `=`, for instance.

Supposing the assumptions mentioned below are fulfilled, the following code should work for you:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
> "OutputXY.txt" (
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B "*.txt" ^| findstr /R "^[0-9][0-9]*\.txt$"') do (
        for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /L "\/f%%~nF\.item\.r" "%%~F"') do (
            setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
            set "LINE=%%L"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            set "LINE=!LINE:*/f%%~nF.item.r=!"
            set "WIDTH=!LINE:*"_width":=!"
            set "HEIGHT=!LINE:*"_height":=!"
            for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%M in ('echo WIDTH^,!WIDTH! ^& echo HEIGHT^,!HEIGHT!') do (
                set "%%M=%%N"
            )
            echo %%~nF  !WIDTH! !HEIGHT!
            endlocal
            endlocal
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

#### Assumptions:

- the pattern `/f`**`X`**`.item.r` is unique in each file, when **`X`** is also the file name;
- the keywords `"_width":` and `"_height":` of interest are the first ones after the `/f`**`X`**`.item.r` pattern;
- the keywords `"_width":` and `"_height":` of interest are in the same line as the preceding `/f`**`X`**`.item.r` pattern;
- the separator after the width and height numbers is the `,`;
- the line of the file containing all the information of interest does not exceed a length of 8190 characters;

#### Explanation:

- the outer `for /F %%F` loop walks through all `*.txt` files that have numeric digits in their names only; this is accomplished by `dir /B`, filtered by `findstr`, because `dir` does not support regular expressions; finally `for /F` parses the output of `findstr`;
- the inner `for /F %%L` loop parses the output of `findstr` which searches the line in the text file that contains the pattern `/f`**`X`**`.item.r`; **`X`** is represented by `%%~nF`, where the `~n` modifier extracts the pure (numeric) file name from the outer `for /F %%F` loop;
- in the body of the nested `for /F` loops, there are several string substitution activities done:

  - at first, everything up to and including the pattern `/f`**`X`**`.item.r` is removed;
  - next, everything up to and including the first occurence of `"_width":` and `"_height":` is removed and stored to separate variables `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT`, respectively;
  - at last, the first `,` and everything after is removed from the values stored in `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` are removed, using another `for /F %%M` loop;
  - [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is toggled in order to avoid any trouble with special characters, like `%` `!` `^` `&` `<` `>` `|`;
- the outermost block is intended for redirecting the output data once only (`> "OutputXY.txt"`) rather than multiple times (appending with `>>`) within the body of the nested `for /F` loops;